# Opening Simulink models created in newer versions of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, version, simulink

I have received a simulink model from one of my students, but as he is using a newer version of MATLAB (8.6) than the one i have installed (8.5) i get an error when i try to open it.
[image]

How can i open it without asking him to save in an older format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actaully quite simple.

I opened the .mdl file in a text editor and search/replaced
8.6->8.5
and 2015b->2015a

Sometimes when doing this an error occurs when opening a model for the first time. After saving it the first time and reopening it this error dissapears.

It should however be noted that if the model contains a new component or if the functionality of a component has been changed this method will not work.

Sigurd

Comment: It is not always enough. If there is a component that comes with the newer version, you cannot open the mdl properly.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Ill put that in the answer as well

Comment: Note that this way of migration may cause parameters to be lost, changing the model behaviour.

Comment: The best solution is to ask the person who sent the model to use the "save as" and save it in the right version: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/saving-a-model.html#f2-86382. Of course, if he or she is using functionality that is not in the version the model is being saved as, he or she will get an error message when doing so.

Comment: May I ask, which .mdl-file you mean? In my folder, after creating two models, I can only find .slx-files, which are just gibberish when opened in vim...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a .slx file that you need to convert, the process is a little different. Using a tool like 7Zip, open the .slx file (a .slx is really just a disguised .zip file) so you can edit it without extracting all the files. Go into the "metadata" folder. Edit each of the .xml files in there and change the tags for `<cp:version>` and `<matlabVersion>`. Save each and have 7Zip update the archive for you.

Like the other responder said though, if you used any part of your model uses features inherent to the newer version, those components will be broken.